# Como criar um atributo de classe com tipos pré-definidos em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consultei na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) do Python, mas não encontrei uma sintaxe de como eu poderia criar um atributo de uma classe que tenha um tipo pré-definido.

Peguei como exemplo esse exercício do [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_class3):

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Penso no caso de termos que restringir as entradas que um usuário possa dar. Por exemplo não gostaríamos que um usuário colocasse uma string em age, ou mesmo que deixasse esse atributo null.
Como podemos pré-determinar o tipo do atributo de uma classe?

Comment: Por alguma razão, quem anda aprendendo programar agora anda confundindo o que é o dado e o topo de dado, principalmente em Python. Essas coisas são muito diferentes, mas deve ter algum material que deve estar ensinando errado porque não é comum muita gente cometer o mesmo erro e há algum tempo atrás isso não acontecia. Se deseja ter tipos nas variáveis deveria usar uma linguagem que faz isso de verdade, Python tem vantagens em não fazer isso, ainda que permita colocar um *hint* de que tipo será a variável. Mas nada garante que o dado será entrado certo.

Answer (score 0):

A partir do python 3.6(se não me engano), ele permite criar classes assim:

```
class Foo:
   nome: str
   idade: int
def __init__(self, nome: str, idade: int):
   self.nome = nome
   self.idade = idade
```

Porém se você quer tipagem forte é mais recomendado você usar ferramentas que ofereçam isso